# CandleDataSet not drawn on Android 6.0.1 devices

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

**Summary:**
CandleDataSet not drawn on Android 6.0.1 and below versions. Only shadow is drawn. On android versions above 6.0.1, CandleDataSet is drawn along with the given Shadow.

**Expected Behavior:**
CandleDataSet should get drawn on Android 6.0.1 devices as well along with Shadow.

**Device:**
LGE Nexus 5, Android Version 6.0.1, Library Version: 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out, in order to plot CandleChart on devices running Android M and below, I needed to disable hardware acceleration via below API:

```
chart.setHardwareAccelerationEnabled(false)
```

this internally sets the Chart's layerType as `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`.